# I am trying to build a simple python program of speech recognition(speech to text) when I try to run this program its throwing an error

Tags: python, machine-learning, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

```
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    audio = r.listen(source)
try:
    print("JARVIS : "+r.recognize_google(audio))
except Exception:
    print("Something went Wrong !!!!!!")
```

error = ALSA lib pulse.c:243:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Connection refused
        ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:486:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid type for card
        ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:486:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid type for card

Comment: Exception explainning the exact cause, what else ?

Comment: why its not working?

Comment: Invalid type for card, fix this.

Comment: What have you tried? What don’t you understand about the error message?!

Comment: I try to search on google but I don't get any related answer to ALSA lib pulse, how do I solve this Invalid type for Card?

Comment: check asound.conf on you system and make sure the arecord cmd is working correctly on your system. check the device index of the microphone.